# How do I restore accidently deleted system library(libpro*)?

Tags: gui, restore

As the title said, I accidentally deleted system libraries which has the name pattern of "libpro*" in usr/lib/. And then, when I reboot the system, graphical user interface is gone away(Ubuntu gnome 16.04). My original intention is to delete google's protobuf library only, but my careless action causes this disaster result. It seems to me that I deleted libproj, libproxy, and etc(libpro*) including google's libproto.
How can I restore my system before deleting the those files? Can I just copy other ubuntu's libpro* files into my system?

Comment: I would login via [text] terminal, go into `/var/log/apt` & copy down what you actually removed; then `apt-get install` the libraries you removed.  If apt-get is mucked up (I doubt it, but I'm not looking that closely), you'll just have to download (`wget` or other) and `dpkg -i` them that way.  Starting with a list of what you did is where I'd start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find which libraries that was deleted by using the command

```
dpkg-query --search /usr/lib/*libpro*
```

Then reinstall them by calling

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lib...
```

for each of the missing libraries
... should be proj, proxy and so forth

Comment: You're probably going to want to make that a little more specific e.g. `dpkg-query --search '/usr/lib/*libpro*'` - otherwise it's going to return pretty much every package that provides a library